# I cannot execute my Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I want to execute my Haskell code but I have an error message that "not in scope morePrime"

```
import Data.List
import System.IO
primeNumbers = [3,5,7,11]
morePrime = primeNumbers ++ [13,17,19]
```

On console

```
Prelude>:l deneme.hs
Main>:r
Main>morePrime
```

I am actually doing them.

**Note:** I am using 7.10.3 ghci

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code? Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes, I am watching a tutorial and I am using the same code. When he executes his code, it is working but I couldn't.

Comment: This is clearly not the code you're executing right now. There's several typos on this that would lead to a failure before it even got to the morePrime part. Actually copy&paste the code you're writing instead of retyping it here.

Comment: Are you typing this in `ghci` ? If yes, then you have to put `let` before `primeNumbers`. Like this: `let primeNumbers = [3,5,7,11]`. And similarly for `morePrimes`.

Comment: @Sibi OP would get a different error if he would typed in `primeNumbers = [3,5,7,11]` in the console itself

Comment: Yes I am using ghci. I put let before them. But still I see  "not in scope morePrime" error.

Comment: Show and tell us your **real** and **full** code and if it is saved in a file or what exactly you do.

Comment: You are doing something else wrong then. This code works perfectly: https://ideone.com/xZBSgq

Comment: I shared my codes as an answer. Can you look it please?

Comment: Just to confirm, when you do `:r` you're getting the message `Ok, modules loaded: Main.`?

Comment: In case it is not abundantly obvious, this code has no obvious error. If you would like help fixing your error, you must include the input/ouput on your console which causes this error *verbatim*. Otherwise, "it isn't working" doesn't help anyone fix your problem.

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks to all !

Comment: @coderbst It is considered polite to write an answer detailing how to fix your problem if you discover what is wrong -- yes, even when it's your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of typos in your imports. I think you mean:

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

primeNumbers = [3,5,7,11]
morePrime = primeNumbers ++ [13,17,19]
```

i.e. `Data.list` should be `Data.List` and `Syste.IO` should be `System.IO`.

Comment: Now I fixed it, but still not working

Comment: Silly question - are you running the code in ghci? if so, are you sure have you loaded it correctly? (with :load <filename>)

Comment: :l filename.hs
:r 
mainPrime

I used this codes.